# How a userdefined functions saved under Table valued function in sql server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Im not sure whether im in right place to ask this question.
But I wonder How a function that i created fall under the table valued function? why cant it be inside scalar function?

I have the below function recorded in a Database.

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.ufnGetTVP', N'FN') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP FUNCTION ufnGetTVP;  
GO  
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnGetTVP(@input varchar(50))  
returns @mt table (a nvarchar(60))
AS   
-- Returns the stock level for the product.  
BEGIN      
declare @output varchar(1)
declare @len int=(select len(@input))
while(@len>0)
begin
set @output =substring(@input,0,2)

set @input=substring(@input,charindex(@output,@input)+2,len(@input))
SET @len=len(@input)

insert into @mt 
Select @OUTPUT 
end
return
END;  
GO
```

if a function will be saved as TVF how a scalar function can created?
Please share your thoughts.
[image]

Comment: Because it returns a table? I feel like this is a trick question somehow.

Comment: Scalar functions are functions that returns a single value - such as int, varchar, bit etc`. Table valued functions are functions that returns a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment - the difference between a Scalar function and a Table valued function is only the return type of the function.
A scalar valued function is a function that returns a scalar (or single) value such as int, varchar, bit etc`, while a table valued function is a function that returns a table.

The basic syntax of creating a scalar functions is the same as the one for creating a table function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION <name>
(
<parameters list>
)
RETURNS <scalar type>
AS
BEGIN
    -- function code goes here
END;
```